# How to add legends when using secondary axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working with a graph consisting of raw numbers by year plotted as a bar chart with a secondary line graph indicating proportion.

```
specie <- c(rep("sorgho" , 6) , rep("poacee" , 6) , rep("banana" , 6) , rep("triticum" , 6) )
condition <- rep(c("normal" , "stress" , "Nitrogen") , 8)
year <- sample(2010:2015, 24, T)
value <- abs(rnorm(24 , 0 , 15))
test_data <- data.frame(specie,condition,year,value) %>% 
  arrange(year, condition)


smrydata <- 
  test_data %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  mutate(total = sum(value)) %>%
  group_by(condition, year) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value),
            prop = value/total, 
            .groups = "drop") %>% 
  arrange(year, condition) %>% 
  distinct()

Max <- max(smrydata$value)


ggplot(smrydata, aes(year, value, group = 1)) +
  scale_linetype_manual("My Legend", values = 1) +
  geom_col(fill = "steelblue") +
  geom_line(aes(y = prop * Max,  linetype = "%"), colour = "orange", size = 2) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis( ~ ./Max, labels = scales::percent)) +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(~condition) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

When I run this code, I can produce my graph with a legend for the proportion line, but I'm not sure how to produce the legend for the bar chart. Ideally they should appear together grouped with the legend title ("My Legend"), and I would prefer the bar chart legend to appear on top of the line legend (blue "n", orange "%").

[image]

(This is not the real data I'm working with, so I am not concerned about some issues with the current plot caused by incomplete data, such as the proportions line not being "0%" when there are no corresponding values)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

You could specify `legend.box.just` in the `theme` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(smrydata) +
  scale_linetype_manual("My Legend", values = 1) +
  geom_col(aes(year, value, group = 1, fill = "steelblue")) +
  geom_line(aes(x = year, y = prop * Max,  linetype = "%"), colour = "orange", size = 2) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis( ~ ./Max, labels = scales::percent)) +
  scale_fill_manual('', values = 'steelblue', label = 'n') +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(~condition) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", 
        legend.box = 'vertical', 
        legend.spacing.y = unit(0.1, 'cm'),
        legend.box.just = "right")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

You should mention the `fill` in your `aes` and you could mention `legend.box='vertical'` in your `theme` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
specie <- c(rep("sorgho" , 6) , rep("poacee" , 6) , rep("banana" , 6) , rep("triticum" , 6) )
condition <- rep(c("normal" , "stress" , "Nitrogen") , 8)
year <- sample(2010:2015, 24, T)
value <- abs(rnorm(24 , 0 , 15))
test_data <- data.frame(specie,condition,year,value) %>% 
  arrange(year, condition)


smrydata <- 
  test_data %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  mutate(total = sum(value)) %>%
  group_by(condition, year) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value),
            prop = value/total, 
            .groups = "drop") %>% 
  arrange(year, condition) %>% 
  distinct()

Max <- max(smrydata$value)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(smrydata) +
  scale_linetype_manual("My Legend", values = 1) +
  geom_col(aes(year, value, group = 1, fill = "steelblue")) +
  geom_line(aes(x = year, y = prop * Max,  linetype = "%"), colour = "orange", size = 2) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis( ~ ./Max, labels = scales::percent)) +
  scale_fill_manual('', values = 'steelblue', label = 'n') +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(~condition) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.box = 'vertical')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Is there a way to "group" the "n" label with the rest of the legend? It looks a bit out of place way above. I'm open to re-doing the entire code if the issue is how it's fundamentally structured prevents ggplot from adding a seamless legend

Comment: Hi @cstrudels, I added some code (see update)!